# Sails.js: How to work with i18n in bootstrap

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, internationalization, sails.js

How to work with i18n in Sails.js' bootstrap?

Here is "res.i18n" in controller's actions, but I don't find some global instance (already initialized) like sails.i18n.

I guess code below should work in bootstrap.js:

```
i18n = require('i18n'),
i18n.configure({
   locales: sails.config.i18n.locales,
   directory: sails.config.appPath + sails.config.i18n.localesDirectory,
   defaultLocale: sails.config.i18n.defaultLocale,
   updateFiles: false,
   extension: '.json'
});
__('Hello');
```

But may be there is some better way?

Answer (score 5):

In sails, i18n has been set up for you already. You can configure i18n in `config/i18n.js` and create locales in the `config/locales/` directory.

As to usage, for your **views** you can use either `i18n()` or `__()`. In your **controller** using `res.i18n()`. [More on that can be found here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/08b3b7b0b3b8652d23ee449ac79278d711075365/translation.md#usage).

As to the **global** method, you can call `sails.__()`.

Answer (score 2):

*sails* sets up most variables for you see source: [hooks/i18n](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/i18n/index.js#L54)
right now you can only config the directory but there is a [pull request](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1848)

you can access *i18n* with `__('Hello')` in your view.

to test it change your browser language
*i18n* with *sails* uses the header [Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)